# What is causing Import Error: "no module named modules"?

Tags: python, python-import

I am working on my first open source project.

While getting everything setup for the project, I followed the README.md step by step.

Now, I run into a problem. When I try to run a test and src scripts, I get the following error,

```
ImportError: No module named modules
```

Now, below is the file structure.

```
../
   /modules
        __init__.py
        /src
            lyrics.py 
        /tests
            test_lyrics.py
```

lyrics.py import statements

```
import modules

def test_lyrics():
    assert('lyrics' == modules.process_query('paradise lyrics')[0])
```

This is where the error "Import Error: modules not found".

Yes, all the requirements on the README were met.

If you want to take a look at the project, check it out [on github](https://github.com/bryg217/JARVIS-on-Messenger).

Comment: Did you include the parent directory to `modules` in `sys.path` or `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: Perhaps you were in the wrong directory when you ran the command.  The current working directory is on `sys.path` by default.

Comment: ... Why do you have an `__init__.py` *above* the `src` directory? Also why is `lyrics.py` trying to do something that seems should be put in `test_lyrics.py`? Usually testing tool will automatically put the `src` directory in your PYTHONPATH. BTW: the github link leads to a 404 page, probably your repository is private?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your module's directory is not being read by your PYTHONPATH. To check this go to your home directory and look for a `.bashrc` or some kind of `.profile` file. You may have to use `ls -a` to see these hidden files. If you don't see your module's address listed, add this to the file:

`export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/my/module/path"`

Make sure the address points to the directory with your highest-level `__init__.py` file as python uses it to read the directory as a python package.

Answer (score 0):

Use `python -m site` to conveniently view the
effect of the $PYTHONPATH env var on `sys.path`.

Code authors will often assume that current directory
is in your path:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=.
```

If you intend to use `.` current directory,
then pay careful attention to which one's in use
at the time the script starts running.
You may want to view this value: `os.getcwd()`

Answer (score 0):

I am maybe a bit late to the party but I can answer and maybe it helps.

1)Check once more your paths.
2)Check that you run with >./myProj arguments more arguments,  and not

> myProj arguments more arguments. Hope it helps even a bit

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a [relative import](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/)

```
from ..modules import process_query
def test_lyrics():
    assert('lyrics' == process_query('paradise lyrics')[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Executing Python from Windows PowerShell had to set the folder from where was executing the code in PYTHONPATH

```
$Env:PYTHONPATH = ".\"
Echo $Env:PYTHONPATH
```

or if adding to existing PYTHONPATH values

```
$Env:PYTHONPATH += ";.\"
Echo $Env:PYTHONPATH
```